# git commit -m "add !empty check" zsh: event not found: empty

Tags: git, zsh, git-commit, oh-my-zsh

I just observed having ! before a git commit message triggers events in zsh.

Not sure if it's zsh issue or git feature. Please explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unrelated to git, your shell is trying to expand the `!`.

Use either `\!` to escape the character or `'`single quotes`'` instead of `"`double quotes`"` to disable the shell's variable/history expansion within the string.

To learn more about your shell's history expansion, have a look at [zsh's User Guide - 3.6.1: History expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide03.html#l55)

The simplest use-case for it is re-running a command with `sudo !!` after  forgetting to specify sudo at the beginning.

---

Side-note with regards to `git commit`:

I strongly recommend **against** using `-m` when committing, because it takes away the chance to notice something being wrong with the commit.

If you don't use `-m` the text editor for message input will have a list of staged/unstaged changes. It's always a good idea to have a short look at those lists before finalizing the commit.

(If you notice something is wrong, just save with empty message and the commit will be aborted)

Answer (score 2):

That seems to be the case [for bash as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33340/7490).

Try and escape that character to avoid any shell-related side-effect:

```
git commit -m "add \!empty check"
# or
git commit -m 'add !empty check'
```

(see [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62928039/git-commit-m-add-empty-check-zsh-event-not-found-empty/62928488#comment111303338_62928488) on single quotes)

Or [turn off history substitution](https://serverfault.com/a/208414/783) using `set +H`.

Comment: so it's a bash feature or git feature? I know to escape but wanted to understand what exactly happened?

Comment: @JagadeshaNH It is not a git feature, only a shell (bash or zsh) feature

Comment: SInglequotes will do it too, I like those for most cases where I'm not specifically after  shell expansions.  `git commit -m 'add !empty check'`.  And they're quicker to type.

Comment: @jthill Good point. I have edited the answer accordingly.